# how do I preserve export PATH?

Tags: bash, ssh, export, qnap

How can I make `ssh admin@nas command` work if `command` is in `/opt/bin`?

On my QNAP NAS File **/root/.ssh/rc**:

```
echo "old path is $PATH"
export PATH=/opt/bin:/opt/sbin:$PATH
echo "new path is $PATH"
```

on my machine:

```
~$ ssh admin@nas 'echo $PATH'
```

returns

```
old path is /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
new path is /opt/bin:/opt/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

so the path variable is not preserved. How can I achieve that?

Edit:
As I mentioned in my comment below the command I'm trying to use is git or, more specific `git-upload-pack` and `git-receive-pack` and probably some others. I want to use them in different locations and occasions and don't want to bother setting up a git config on every machine I use it on or teach my IDE how to communicate with my NAS but rather have my NAS conforming standards. So i figured that all I need is to set the right `$PATH`

Edit II:
what i did try so far was also inserting the `export PATH=...` as well as adding another `echo` (to verify they're run) to `~/.bash_profile`, `to /etc/profile` and to `~/.bashrc`. Apparently none of them are even executed when I run a non-interactive command like above. If I do `ssh admin@nas` all of them are executed, but that doesn't help

Comment: stick it in ~/.bash_profile

Comment: i tried that along with adding another echo (to verify they're run) to `~/.bash_profile`, to `/etc/profile` and to `~/.bashrc`. Apparently none of them are even executed when I run a non-interactive command like above. If I do `ssh admin@nas` all of them are executed, but that doesn't help

Comment: How about `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: As described in my previous comment, I tried that

Comment: log into root using `su -`

Comment: I ended up creating Symlinks to the commands in question in `/bin`. That works for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are logged in as admin, `~/.bashrc` is not used but `~/.profile` is. So you can add this to .profile:

```
export PATH=\
/bin:\
/sbin:\
/opt/bin:\  #<--- HERE IT IS NOW
/usr/bin:\
/usr/sbin:\
/usr/bin/X11:\
/usr/local/bin
```

And PATH will be loaded like this when you login as admin. What I did on my nas is I added this to .bashrc, and changed .profile to have only 1 line:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

So when you login as admin, you still get SH configured with .bashrc.

EDIT:
I now understand what you want to do...

Just create symbolic links to those two binaries inside /usr/bin. For example:

```
cd /usr/bin && ln -s /opt/bin/git-upload-pack
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enter `real address` of command instead of command in ssh admin@nas `command`. Like below:

`ssh admin@nas /opt/bin/command-name`

Comment: thanks for the reply, this does work but the command I'm trying to use is git or, more specific `git-upload-pack` and `git-receive-pack` and probably some others. I want to use them in different locations and occasions and don't want to bother setting up a git config on every machine I use it on or teach my IDE how to communicate with my NAS but rather have my NAS conforming standards. So i figured that all I need is to set the right `$PATH`